# Which way to go when Zipping files on a cloud bucket?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, stream, zip, google-cloud-storage

I have a pipeline process which streams data from DB, maps them, and convert the mapped data into XML, then finally create the files on google cloud.

Think of it as this way

```js
pipeline(
 [
  db_stream(),
  mapJsonStream(),
  convertToXmlStream(),
  checkIfNewFileIsNeeded(),
  // option 1. Add a zipping stream here before writing to the cloud
  writeToCloudStream()
  callback()               // cleanup stuff - option 2. I can re-stream files and zip them here and stream back to cloud bucket
 ]
)
```

This will create multiple xml files (there's a limit on each xml file size, so our data needs to be split to different xml files) on the bucket.

Now I need all these files to be zipped, I searched if I can do that directly on the cloud using google Nodejs client, but it seems they don't support this kinda functionality.

I am a bit confused how to proceed because after searching abit I found that all zip libraries needs to built the archive in memory before streaming it which defeats the purpose of the pipeline I already have (option 1)

Option 2 seems a bit expensive and unnecessary.

If you any thoughts on this I would really appreciate it, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's that "pipeline"? WHere is it running? In addition, you can't zip files with Cloud Storage (only gzip a single file). So, you need a step to create your zip and then upload it to  Cloud Storage

Comment: Pipeline is the nodejs stream pipeline function.
 I am thinking now that I will stream the xml files from the cloud, concurrently zip them and stream that back to the cloud.

As far as I understood from reading different sources online, a zip archive will be built in memory and having it as a step in the pipeline will slow it down (it is pretty fast at the moment) - My thought is to create this archive at the end, so even if it fails, I still create the XML files which are of atmost priority for me

Comment: Have you found a solution? if so, can you share your solution as an answer?

Comment: @RoopaM, I actually ended up uploading all files to the cloud, and doing the zipping by downloading all of them and zipping them, then upload the archive.

The download, zip, upload process is a separate process from generating and uploading separate files.